# Untracked file causes failure in git push

Tags: git

I originally added a really big file - after failing to push, I untracked the file using `git rm subposts.xml --cached`.

`git ls-tree -r master --name-only` does not show the too big post.

I then created a new commit.

However, when I do `git push origin master`, I still a failure and it cites the untracked file as being too large.

This is not a copy of another post (the `git rm --cached` command) because the answer in that post did not resolve my issue.

Results of git log (the first commit introduces the large file):

```
commit db81c3895a00ba2298e77a5daccb5c7f95c27544 (HEAD -> master)
Author: 
Date:   Mon Apr 8 17:50:32 2019 -0400

    untrack subposts.xml

commit 1de84132e1171b43d3bc0b9f491619a555933144
Author: 
Date:   Mon Apr 8 17:49:07 2019 -0400

    TF program

commit 2193588f8606d8f20743e4f4d423a7db882ec7a4
Author: 
Date:   Mon Apr 8 17:45:44 2019 -0400

    first commit
```

Comment: in my post i explain that I used `git rm --cached <file>` which is the answer in that post

Comment: `git rm --cached` removes the file from the index. The index is the proposed *next* commit. **No existing commit has been changed by this action.** See the linked duplicate for more (though it's probably not the best q&a); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46023509/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274126/1256452 in particular.

Comment: If you believe this is not a duplicate, please provide the output of `git log`, annotated with the commit that introduced the large file, if one exists.

Comment: @torek Yeah I admit I hesitated about which was the most canonical. The subject is one of the most attracting ones, and there are plenty of questions. Open to suggestions ^^

Comment: Which commit introduced the large file?

Comment: @merlin2011 the first commit

Comment: @RomainValeri I think the second duplicate is probably closer. Duplicates are rarely totally exact...